# Scroller Event Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.6

I am facing a really very serious issue, will using Scroller Container in Flex 4.6 Mobile Project. I am not able to capture the Scroll Event. I believe they have removed the scroll event from Flex 4.6 Mobile. Please suggest some work around for it.

Answer (score 0):

The scroller itself doesn't dispatch an event (has been that way with since Flex 4 if I remember correct). You have listen to change events on the scroller's viewport.

You can read more about scrollers and viewports [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Spark+Viewport).